# IOS Application Freezes

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

My application is freezing with a reason that I could not figure out, it does not crash but it freezes.

basically what I did was having another view inside my view that is hidden at first place, after when I click a button this view will be appeared and it includes a UItextfield and a UIPickerView. the pickerview data is updating while I edt the UItextfield and I select one of the values from picker view then basically press addButton, when I add thi whole view will be hidden again and the selected value of the pickerview will be added another UITextfield in the main view.

when I do this first time it works fine. it sets the value of the UI textfield which is on the main view to the correct value. but when I try to change it, get that view unhidden and select another value in the pcikerview and press on addButton again the application freezes. No crash appears.

I want to inform you about this the value of the UITextfield on the main view is changing I checked it on the logs. and the method that do the clicking action completely works. But it freezes.

I couldnt figure it out, I need some help :)

EDIT:

I figure out that the UITextField on the main view cause this freeze, when I set the text

```
[myTextfield setText:@"somethng"];
```

the UI freeze. when I comment this out it works pretty fine. But It works fine at first time. does not work on the second time.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT 2 (I added some code):

```
-(IBAction)addButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pickerViewDoneClicked:)];

    [[self.navigationController.navigationBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton];

    [self.pickerContainer setHidden:NO];
}

-(IBAction)pickerViewDoneClicked:(id)sender
{

    [[self.navigationController.navigationBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.myTextField);
    NSLog(@"old val %@", self.myTextField.text);


    // the text field on the main view.
    [self.myTextField setText: selectedText];

    NSLog(@"new val %@", self.myTextField.text);

    [self.pickerContainer setHidden:YES];
}

//in picker view source
selectedText = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
```

As I told the first time I add it works fine I can see the value on the textfield
but when I do the same action again and click done the app freezes.

I checked the reference of the textfield before after and no reference missing 
I can see the new value and old value as well. but the UI freezes.

Comment: you will probably need to post the relevant code if you want help

Comment: When the app freezes, check console for error log. I guess the app freezes due to some error, and may crash after some time (say after 10-15 secs).

Comment: Without few pieces of code. Nobody could ever help.. Its good that you problem is solved. But Since nobody can figure out why the problem was occurring and how it was solved. I would suggest you to better close the question.

Comment: there is no log except the logs I enter. and the app is not crashing..

Comment: it still not solved. I still get the same problem. I will definetely share the answer if i can figure out... :(

Comment: can you explain more with source code user94...

Comment: guys I found the problem it is about my padding code. I will post the answer and check it accepted answer but I need to wait 8 hours for my rate issue. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this piece of code for padding for my text field,

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 20)];
self.myTextField.leftView = paddingView;
self.myTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

I am not sure how it effects it but second time I change the text into the textfield I was getting my screen freezed.

Thanks again for any effort to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: you do not perform any call to UIKit on non-main thread?